# Click function not triggering when Used with ResponsiveSlides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a J Query slider called ResponsiveSlides.js v1.54  .

I am trying to triger a click function on document ready but its not happening .

**HTML**

```
<ul class="rslides">
    <li><img class="thumb" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/313/523/3135232000RC/580X420/8079d3bd4e020363bcdbaebaa8bf55a6.JPG" name="primary" id="primary"> 
    </li>
  <li><img id="primary" class="thumb" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/318/270/318270100000/580X420/0f93b6672ccde6fdc78b19077df8ba25.jpg" name="primary"></li>
  <li><img src="http://images01.inmotico.com/313/523/3135232000RC/580X420/5c63a9d68cfc0d28f5ea8dc655258871.JPG" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://images01.inmotico.com/313/523/3135232000RC/580X420/7eda3992653969535866af22ae122d7d.JPG" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav',function(event){
alert('clicked');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.transparent-btns_nav').trigger('click');


     $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({

        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 540,
        namespace: "transparent-btns"
      });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4PQLr/5/)

As you can see in my script . A click function is added to an element . so when that element is clicked the alert should poup which is working fine ... but the alert should also popup when page is loaded . Which is not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: `alert` will never come when page is loaded as it's not written to be called on load, it's written on click handler!

Comment: This code is a mess. and don't use `$(document).on` read the `on` docs about delegate events.

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with class `transparent-btns_nav`. I dont find any in your fiddle source.

Comment: If i'm not wrong  the  elements with this class `.transparent-btns_nav`, appears due to `.responsiveSlides({...})` slider. so if you call the trigger function  before initializing the  responsiveSlides `.responsiveSlides({...})`, then  those elements wont exist, it would exist after the slider is initialised.

Comment: @dreamweiver exactly bro . I had answered before itself but Stack is not letting me accept my own answer until two more days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things and this is how it will work

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4PQLr/7/)

SO my explanation how we I fixed it .

I was initializing the

```
$('.transparent-btns_nav').trigger('click');
```

before the script

```
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({

        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 540,
        namespace: "transparent-btns"
      });
```

hence the trigger was happening for a div which did not existed . So now here is the script which will work properly

```
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav',function(event){
alert('clicked');
});

$(document).ready(function(){      
     $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({

        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 540,
        namespace: "transparent-btns"
      });
    $('.transparent-btns_nav').trigger('click');

});
```

Please let me know if you agree with my answer Thanks

Comment: yes thats the right way of triggering the click event elements, since they exist only after the slider is initialised. anyway since you got your answer, just close this question by self answering.